# Interpolation error for x*atan(x)

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate x*atan(x) on [-5, 5] using (n+1) equidistant nodes. The oscillations on the ends seem to be caused by the same reasons Runge phenomenon is. The question is why exactly are they occuring and if they will diminish provided n tends to infinity (the nodes should still be equidistant).

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: A simple discussion is in Wikipedia on [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the same as the Runge phenomenon.  The Runge phenomenon comes about because sines and cosines do not have discontinuities, so have trouble fitting functions that have them.  They can get there pointwise, but it takes a lot of terms and you have the overshoot because the high order terms are trying to compensate for badly fitting low order terms.  Polynomials do not like having equally spaced roots, so you tend to get overshoot at the ends of the interval.  Sines and cosines have equally spaced roots and are a much better choice if you are using equally spaced nodes.

Comment: By Runge phenomenon I mean that interpolation error of $\frac{(1)(1+x^2)}$ on [-5, 5] with equidistant nodes grows near the ends of the interval when n grows.

Comment: Yes, that will continue.  Whether you consider it the same reason may be a question of taste.  In the Fourier case, it is a mismatch between the fitting functions and the function to be fitted.  In this case it is a mismatch between the fitting functions and the nodes.  I can't draw a clear linkage between the two, which would make it easier to say they have the same cause.

Comment: @RossMillikan: isn't what you described in your answer **Gibbs** phenomenon instead of Runge? Runge is kind of complicated, having to do with the location of the poles of the analytic continuation of the function to $\mathbb{C}$. (My memory of the argument is a bit hazy at the moment.) Details are explained in https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1987.12000642 But given that $\tan^{-1}$ has the same poles as $1 / (1+x^2)$ (at $\pm i$) probably (I am guessing here) the same Runge phenomenon will happen.

Comment: @WillieWong:  I think what I (and I think OP) was describing as Runge is in fact Gibbs, the overshoot of Fourier series in the presence of a discontinuity.  The oscillation of polynomial interpolation is Runge.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) says they are related but does not give details.

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems that $x*atan(x)$ has a pole in $i$, as $atan(i)$ is $i*\infty$. Thus, the same proof as for Runge's function may apply.